# SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides does not run first time in IE, works on refresh

Tags: 2013, client-side-rendering

So I have some JS that is supposed to take a related list, remove the ID column, auto-populate it, remove the hero links, and remove the add column button.  In Chrome and Edge, it executes this correctly every time.  Only in IE does it not work on the first load, but it works on refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens", function() {

    function init() {
        var overrideComplete = false;
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function () {
            var viewId = '{08F90997-D401-49A9-A91A-061C990F840D}';
            var orderFieldValue = GetUrlKeyValue("ID"); // ID of the master item
            var orderFieldInternalName = "CCR_x0020_ID"; // Internal name of the lookup field           

            // Switch to edit view and hide "Add column" button
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', function () {
                g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.canUserAddColumn = false;
                g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.showAddColumn = false;
                InitGridFromView(viewId);
            });
            console.log("changed to edit mode");

            SP.SOD.executeFunc('clienttemplates.js', 'SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens', function () {
                var done = false;
                SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

                    OnPostRender: [function (ctx) {
                        console.log("override entered");
                        overrideComplete = true;

                        if (ctx.view != viewId || ctx.enteringGridMode || !ctx.inGridMode || done)
                            return;

                        // Hide quick links (aka "hero") row
                        var hero = $get('Hero-' + ctx.wpq);
                        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
                        wrapper.style.display = 'none';
                        hero.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, hero);
                        wrapper.appendChild(hero);

                        // Fetch JSGrid object
                        var jsGridContainer = $get("spgridcontainer_" + g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.qualifier)
                        var jsGrid = jsGridContainer.jsgrid;

                        // Automatically update master lookup column
                        var lock = 0;
                        jsGrid.AttachEvent(SP.JsGrid.EventType.OnEntryRecordCommitted, function (args) {
                            if (lock == 0) {
                                lock = 1;
                                var update = SP.JsGrid.CreateUnvalidatedPropertyUpdate(args.recordKey, orderFieldInternalName, orderFieldValue, false);
                                jsGrid.UpdateProperties([update], SP.JsGrid.UserAction.UserEdit);
                                lock = 0;
                            }
                        });

                        // Make columns non-sortable and non-filterable
                        // var columns = jsGrid.GetColumns();
                        // for (var i in columns)
                        // {
                        //     columns[i].isSortable = false;
                        //     columns[i].isAutoFilterable = false;
                        // }
                        // jsGrid.UpdateColumns(new SP.JsGrid.ColumnInfoCollection(columns));

                        // Hide master lookup column
                        jsGrid.HideColumn(orderFieldInternalName);
                        jsGrid.HideColumn("Requested_x0020_By");

                        done = true;
                    },]

                });

            });
        });
    }   

RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("../../../SiteAssets/JSGrid-masterDetails.js"), init);
init();

});

</script>
```

The issue occurs at SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides.  This function is never entered when it loads, but it is entered when the refresh happens.

I have been Googling for this issue and I cannot find a single case like this.  I even put IE in compatibility mode and it still does this behavior.  This is very bizarre behavior and multiple users are experiencing it.  Expecting users to know to refresh each time they load is not going to work either.

Answer (score 0):

i've experience this in the past, you have to disable the minimal strategy download site feature

Comment: I tried that. It was still doing it. That is what the registerModuleInit is supposed to handle. Submitting this for mds to load it.

Comment: and you added this to the JSLink as ~SiteCollection/SiteAsets/JSGrid-masterDetails.js 

probabbly you have something wrong in the jslink reference

Comment: I have a content editor with the link as `../../../SiteAssets/JSGrid-masterDetails.js`.  When I test the link, it pops up the js file.  I don't think there is an issue with this, because this only happens in IE on the first load.  Refreshes are fine.  I tried to make a script editor instead of a content editor, but that made everything go really bad until I removed it.